# Javascript remove warning symbol in popup

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

If I use alert, the warning symbol will be present in the popup as given below. Is it possible to display a popup without warning symbol in javascript?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change/replace the icon. Actually, in Chrome icon is *not* displayed.
I would suggest using jQuery UI. [Check out this link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to change anything about the built-in `alert()` and `confirm()` popups except for the text of the message - this is a browser security feature.

You can simulate a popup dialog by building one from HTML using a transparent `<div>` to cover the rest of your page so that users can't interact with the rest of the page until the dialog closes. (Or use a translucent `<div>` to make it more obvious to the user that the rest of the page is "disabled".)

I would not bother coding this from scratch when there are lots of JS libraries that do it for you. The [jQuery dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) is pretty easy to use, to name just one option.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced all my `alert()` with [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) (+1 to Igor)

If anyone wants to do it easily, here is what I did:

Simply include jQuery UI, eg.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

and create this JavaScript function

```
function AlertUi(title, message) {
  if (!(/<\/?[a-z]{1,3} ?\/?>/.test(message))) // Probably not HTML (edit this line as you wish)
    message = message.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>'); // Replace \n with <br/>

  $("<div title='" + title + "'>" + message + "</div>").dialog(); // Show the popup
}
```

Then you could do a Replace All using any text editor, replacing `alert(` with `AlertUi('',`, eg.

```
alert('Hello');
```

becomes

```
AlertUi('', 'Hello');
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using cool dialog modal, called [colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example4/index.html), Its awesome at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a pop-up instead of an alert.  Then you can set it to whatever size you want with whatever you want in it.

```
function newPopup(url) {

    params = 'width=whatever';
    params += 'height=whatever';
newwindow = window.open(url, 'name', params);
    if (window.focus) { newwindow.focus() }
    return false;
}
```

Then just build your popup window and call it in an onClick() function.